# Asp.net Identity, inheritance of IdentityUserLogins class

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, identity

I use Asp.net Identity. I would like add some extra columns to table AspnetUserLogins (column Firstname, Lastname). In order to that I inherited class `IdentityUserLogins`like

```
public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin
{
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In application I use function to add external logins to certain user by    UserManager    class, this way:

```
ExternalLoginInfo eInfo = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo();
var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
IdentityResult result = manager.AddLogin(this.User.Identity.GetUserId(), eInfo.Login);`
```

Everything works fine. This code add new record to `AspnetUserLogins` table and unfortunately insert     `"IdentityUserLogin"` value to `Discriminator` column. Is there posibility how to say `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`class to use subclass `ApplicationUserLogin` instead of  `IdentityUserLogin` (and fill discriminator column with `"ApplicationUserLogin"` value?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this correct, you need to update all `IdentityUserLogin` related tables and inheritance as follows.

ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin, IdentityRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{

}
```

Your Db contenxt:

```
public class YourDataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser , IdentityRole, string,   ApplicationUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{    

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserLogin>().ToTable("TableName");

       //Any relevant model bindings.

    }
}
```